# Magento Configurable Options

Tags: magento

I have a configurable option for Color.
I have managed to display the labels (red,blue,green) for it within A tags on the product view page.

What I want to do is when I click on red tell Magento that I've selected Red and when I click on add to cart it adds the product with the red selection.

I'm not good at Javascript!

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

magento alredy knows what's your selection if you are inserting it as a custom option(see you order in admin)